# how make aikau ComboBox pass vallue instead of name?

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo, aikau

Here is aikau Combobox usage:

```
{
    name: "alfresco/forms/controls/ComboBox",
    config: {
        fieldId: "someFieldId",
        label: "myListName",
        name: "assoc_sc_goods",
        addedAndRemovedValues: true,
        valueDelimiter: ",",
        firstValueIsDefault: false,
        showAllOptionsOnOpen: true,
        searchStartsWith: true,
        optionsConfig: {
                    queryAttribute: "label",
                    labelAttribute: "label",
                    valueAttribute: "name",
            publishTopic: "ALF_GET_FORM_CONTROL_OPTIONS",
            publishPayload: {
                resultsProperty: "options",
                url: url.context + "/proxy/alfresco/slingshot/datalists/lists/node/workspace/SpacesStore/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
                itemsAttribute: "datalists",
                labelAttribute: "name",
                valueAttribute: "nodeRef"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It displays all values from list with UUID `11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111` well, e.g. it shows names instead of nodeRef values. But when I press button on form, it sends

```
 "assoc_sc_goods_added": "goodName"
```

While it is expected

```
 "assoc_sc_goods_added": "workspace://SpacesStore/22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222"
```

Where `22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222` is UUID of selected list item.

It seems that `Combobox` request json, extract values for html select by `labelAttribute` but when it comes to apply selected values it `forget` to convert selected `labelAttribute` back to `valueAttribute`.

How configure aikau `Combobox` to fix such issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change both `valueAttribute` settings to be "nodeRef" - currently only one of them is.

Comment: Tried. It does not help.